# get customized attributes value from switch toggle

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement

I am trying to get value of the attribute 'data-id'. But when i try to get the value of 'data-id' from onchange eventhandler. I am getting a null value.

```
 function handleChange(event, e, id) {
            const currentID = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
}

return(
settings.map(item => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                                <div>
                                    <Switch
                                        checked={item.value}
                                        color="primary"
                                        name="checkedB"
                                        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
                                        onChange={(event, e) => handleChange(event, e, item.ltbAppSettingID)}
                                        id={"firmSwitch-"+item.settingName}
                                        data-id={item.settingName}
                                    />
                                    <label class="checkLabel" htmlFor={item.ltbAppSettingID}>

                                        <span>{item.name}</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange#syntax), the onchange global handler accepts one and only argument, which is the event. You give it two (`event`, and `e`).

Try replacing with that:

```
 function handleChange(e, id) {
            const currentID = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
}

return(
settings.map(item => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                                <div>
                                    <Switch
                                        checked={item.value}
                                        color="primary"
                                        name="checkedB"
                                        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
                                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, item.ltbAppSettingID)}
                                        id={"firmSwitch-"+item.settingName}
                                        data-id={item.settingName}
                                    />
                                    <label class="checkLabel" htmlFor={item.ltbAppSettingID}>

                                        <span>{item.name}</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            }
)
```

EDIT: didn't realize it was a [MaterialUI Switch Component](https://material-ui.com/fr/api/switch/)

As you can see from the link, you can't just add any attribute to these components like you would with vanilla JS. If you have to retrieve it for some reason, I'm afraid you'll have to store it elsewhere.

Comment: at first i tried like that it was giving bool value.  incase of react switch it was giving bool value to 1st parameter expect our passed value

Comment: is there other way to show switch where can i get value of added attributes

Comment: Why don't you pass it as a parameter to your `handleChange()` function? That should do what you want to achieve. Even better, just pass `item` to your handleChange function and you'll have all the attributes here.